# Bootstrap 3: Form styles failing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjL4f2ew/) with full code example.

I would like:

- The entire "page content" `container` (that is, the `<h1>` that starts "*Sign in to...*" as well as the entire `<form>` element) to be centered in the screen; and
- The "*Need help?*" link needs to be left aligned, aligning with the submit button's left side

I am trying to style center the container via `text-center`. I am trying to align the link via `text-left`. Neither are working:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
            <h1 class="strong-primary">Sign in to continue to Audit<b>Cloud</b>.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signin-email" placeholder="Your email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signin-password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn form-control btn-lg btn-success">Sign in</button>
                <div class="form-group"><a href="#" class="text-left">Need help?</a></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `text-align:left;` to the containing `<div>`.  Instead of `class="text-left`, use `style="text-align:left;`.  I put those changes into your fiddle:

### http://jsfiddle.net/fjL4f2ew/1/

Comment: Thanks @God is good (+1) - what about my first question though (centering the whole page content container? I see in your fiddle that it is still not centered, any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, followup question: how did you know that I needed to change `class="text-left"` to `text-align: left;` in the parent `<div>`? Just trying to understand how you solved that problem.

Comment: There was no CSS for the class `text-left`.  That's why it didn't work :)  I'm working on the centering now.

Comment: Thanks again @God is good (+1) - but yes, Bootstrap 3 has so-called [Text Alignment Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment). Did you find evidence to support the contrary?

Comment: The only evidence I had was that IT DIDN'T WORK.  So I just used the way that I'm used to.  I don't use bootstrap, sorry.  I'm just working with the code that I already know :)

Comment: Makes sense :-) thanks again @God is good (+1). Any idea about the centering of the h1 & form?